# How to bring the first view in stack view to front in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 views in stack view. The spacing value is -15, because I want the second view be under the first view with -15 spacing.
The spacing is ok but the first view is under the second one.
I tried setting the first view zPosition, but it didn't work.

```
firstViewlayer.zPosition = 1;
```

Comment: This does not sound like a good use of stack view.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options.

1. you could ask the stackview to bring the coresponding view to front. stackview.bringSubviewToFront(firstView)
   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622541-bringsubviewtofront
2. or you add them completely manually. Fist add the as *subviews*. (the fist view last in this case) and the add them as *addArrangedSubview* (the fist view fist in this case)

But bringSubviewToFront is probably the fastest way

Comment: Thanks. I called bringSubviewToFront in cellForRowAtIndexPath. it didn't solve the problems.

Comment: Thx, this is the correct solution when dealing with UIStackView.